# controlling mouse in 4 types can't work with python

Tags: python, mouse, controlling

I tried four types of mouse controller to move my mouse in video game(like valorant), but they all didn't work. why?

```
import time
import win32api
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import mouse

print('start')
time.sleep(1)

print("type1")
pyautogui.moveTo(300, 300, 2)
time.sleep(1)

print("type2")
pydirectinput.moveTo(300, 300)
time.sleep(1)

print("type3")
mouse.move("300", "300")
time.sleep(1)

print("type4")
win32api.SetCursorPos((300,300))
print("done")
```

Comment: I highly suggest using the code block feature so that it is easier to read the code.

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience caused. This is my first time asking question.

Comment: any updates here? I guess you need intercept mouse driver, but interceptions are blocked from valorant too

Comment: thanks, I found a method it can work on  APEX. But its accuracy is not good.